# Angular 8: Wait for subscribe response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some issue in my auth guard  when I request for some data from the server 
and my decide for routing is dependent on the response from server
how can I wait for the server response for the next step?

this is my code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this._sessionService.user) {
        this._router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }

    this._userServiceProxy.get(this._sessionService.userId).subscribe((user: UserDto) => {
        if (user["result"].shouldChangePassword) {
            this._router.navigate([this.routeToChangePassword()]);
        }
        if ((!route.data || !route.data["permission"])) {
            return true;
        }

        if ((this._permissionChecker.isGranted(route.data["permission"]))) {
            return true;
        }
        this._router.navigate([this.selectBestRoute()]);
        return false;
    })

}
```

Comment: A guard can return an Observable<boolean>, precisely for the cases where the decision to authorize navigation is a asynchronous. Don't subscribe. Use the RxJS map operator to transform your Observable<UserDto> into an Observable<boolean>, and return that Observable<boolean>.

Comment: @JB Nizet can you give an example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
if (!this._sessionService.user) {
    this._router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
}

return this._userServiceProxy.get(this._sessionService.userId).pipe(map((user: UserDto) => {
    if (user["result"].shouldChangePassword) {
        this._router.navigate([this.routeToChangePassword()]);
    }
    if ((!route.data || !route.data["permission"])) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((this._permissionChecker.isGranted(route.data["permission"]))) {
        return true;
    }
    this._router.navigate([this.selectBestRoute()]);
    return false;
}))

}
```

Returned the observable from `canActivate` and use pipe + map instead of `subscribe`.

Comment: thank you  @yashpatelyk . do you have any courses about rxjs operators?

Comment: I don't have courses but I think official documentation is good enough. It also has examples. https://www.learnrxjs.io/